# WatchKit / Healthkit - Unable to create a swimming HKWorkout Session

Tags: watchkit, healthkit

I'm setting configuration for a HKWorkout session as follows:

```
self.configuration = [[HKWorkoutConfiguration alloc] init];
self.configuration.activityType = HKWorkoutActivityTypeSwimming;
self.configuration.locationType = HKWorkoutSessionLocationTypeOutdoor;
self.configuration.swimmingLocationType = HKWorkoutSwimmingLocationTypeOpenWater;

HKWorkoutSession *session = [[HKWorkoutSession alloc] initWithConfiguration:self.configuration error:&error];
if (error)
{        
    NSLog(@"Error with Healthkit Session: %@", error);
}
if (session == nil) 
{
    NSLog(@"*** Unable to create the workout session: %@ ***", error.localizedDescription);
    abort();
}
```

I'm using Xcode 8 but for that matter it also appears in the simulators for Xcode 8 beta 3 too. Using Apple Series 2 Watch Simulator of course.

And I get the following error. Is there something that I am doing horribly wrong here or is there another way to test swimming workout sessions?

*** Unable to create the workout session: Swimming sessions are not supported on this device ***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swimming workouts cannot be tested on the Apple Watch simulator. You must use Series 2 hardware to test.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of stating the obvious, can you test it on an actual watch?

I've never tried doing exactly what you are doing here, but there are lots of other functions that aren't supported on the emulators - and looking at the error message that appears to be the case here.

Sorry I can't be more help

Comment: yes - but this is an issue with simulators right... or maybe a combination of setup? Unsure - off to upgrade my watch.